# How to install .Net Framework 2.0 without harming 3.5 and 4.0 already installed?

Tags: .net

I've got quite a complex .Net 2.0 project to build (with VS 2010) which does not build without 2.0 version of System.ServiceModel.dll and does not run if compiled with .Framework 4.0. Can I install Net Framework 2.0 safely after 3.5 and 4.0? Or where can I download an old System.ServiceModel .dll assembly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The framework 3.5 includes the 3.0 and the 2.0 so it should suffice. Note however that System.ServiceModel.dll was released with the framework 3.0 and has the version 3.0.0.0. The only System.ServiceModel.dll with version 2.0.0.0 that ever shipped was with early CTPs of WCF (see the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you for information, Julien. Would you be so kind to send me that old System.ServiceModel.dll with version 2.0.0.0 from some of those CTPs if you have one in your location? If yo can, send it here, please: tabazasypajacone@tempomail.fr

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't have this assembly anymore. If you can, you should consider upgrading to the release version.

Answer (score 2):

you could try one of the all in one installers... here is a link to one of them there are many others out there.

http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/08/18/easily-install-all-versions-of-net-framework-plus-hotfixes-with-aio-runtimes/

here is another:

http://agnipulse.com/2009/08/the-smallest-all-in-one-net-framework-installer/